# Why is a const long converted into short in IL?

Tags: .net, il

Simple curiosity, this code

```
    private const long constLong = 16;
    private static long instanceLong = 16;

    static long constTest()
    { 
        long i = 4;
        return i + constLong;
    }

    static long instanceTest()
    {
        long i = 4;
        return i + instanceLong;
    }
```

produce this IL:

```
.field private static literal int64 constLong = int64(16)
.field private static int64 instanceLong

.method private hidebysig static int64 constTest () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2068
    // Code size 9 (0x9)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int64 i
    )

    IL_0000: ldc.i4.4
    IL_0001: conv.i8
    IL_0002: stloc.0
    IL_0003: ldloc.0
    IL_0004: ldc.i4.s 16
    IL_0006: conv.i8
    IL_0007: add
    IL_0008: ret
} // end of method Program::constTest

.method private hidebysig static int64 instanceTest () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2080
    // Code size 11 (0xb)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int64 i
    )

    IL_0000: ldc.i4.4
    IL_0001: conv.i8
    IL_0002: stloc.0
    IL_0003: ldloc.0
    IL_0004: ldsfld int64 ConsoleApplication1.Program::instanceLong
    IL_0009: add
    IL_000a: ret
} // end of method Program::instanceTest
```

Why does constTest() have [ldc.i4.s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldc_i4_s.aspx)?

```
    IL_0004: ldc.i4.s 16
    IL_0006: conv.i8
```

Instead of [ldc.i8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldc_i8.aspx):

```
    IL_0004: ldc.i8 16
```

Because now the constTest() need to do a [conv.i8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.conv_i8.aspx).

Like I said, this is pure curiosity.

Comment: Your `instanceLong` variable if very confusingly named, given that it's still `static`...

Comment: The IL representation is shorter.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I always had problem at naming variable, go ahead and put a better name :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more compact this way, see the labels for hints.

```
IL_0000: ldc.i4.4
IL_0001: conv.i8
IL_0002: stloc.0
```

This took one byte for `ldc.i4.4` and one byte for `conv.i8`: two bytes total.

```
IL_0004: ldc.i4.s 16
IL_0006: conv.i8
IL_0007: add
```

That took two bytes for `ldc.i4.s` and `16` and one byte for the `conv.i8`: three bytes total.

And `ldc.i8 16` would take one byte for the instruction and 4 bytes for the operand (16): total 5 bytes.

But keep in mind that shorter IL does not mean faster (or slower) native once once it will be JIT'ed (or AOT'ed).

Comment: make sense, i changed constLong to long.MaxValue and now it look like this `IL_0004: ldc.i8 9223372036854775807` and `IL_000d: add`

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you are looking at the IL, not the final machine code. The object of IL is to capture code/programmer intent as closely as possible so that the JITTER can perform the best possible optimization.

If the JITTER was doing this there would be a concern, but there is no concern when the compiler does this.

Comment: “capture code/programmer intent as closely as possible” But that doesn't explain the code in question. Because the closest representation is `ldc.i8 16`.

Comment: No, because it fits in a short and for SOME machine architectures that would be optimal; just not any you are considering using. So the compiler captures as much information as it can and lets the JITTER optimize the code for performance.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is 'that is the way the compiler produces the code'. You have to remember that the native code that is actually produced can run on 32- or 64-bit CPUs. The IL is compiled to the target instruction set and so:

```
  ldc.i4 4
  conv.i8
```

Could well become a single load on a 64-bit CPU.

Comment: @Fredou Rob is talking about the JIT-compiled native code (assembly), not the IL.